# recursive function in php app with $_SESSION arrays

Tags: php

Im trying to build an ap in php to learn foreign languages. I got an function in it that builds a form and starts the test. it looks like:

```
public function test($pol_ang)
    {
        $words = $this->wordsArray();
        if($pol_ang == 1)
        {
            $_SESSION['correctAnswers'] = $this->answersPolAng($words);
        }else {$_SESSION['correctAnswers'] = $this->answersAngPol($words);}

        if(isset($_POST['btn-confirm']))
        {
            $answer = strip_tags($_POST['txt_word']);

            if($answer != "")
            {
                $_SESSION['usersAnswerArray'][$_SESSION['licznik']-1] = $answer;
                $_SESSION['licznik']++;
            }

            if($_SESSION['licznik'] > count($words))
            {

                unset($_SESSION['licznik']);
                $this->auth_user->redirect('result.php');
            }
        }

        if(empty($_SESSION['licznik']))
        {
            $_SESSION['licznik'] = 1;
        }

        ?>
        <form method="post" class="form-signin">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php echo $_SESSION['licznik'].' z '.count($words); ?></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <?php
                            $word = explode(";",$words[($_SESSION['licznik']-1)]);
                            if($pol_ang == 1)
                            {
                                ?>
                                <td><?php echo $word[0]; ?></td>
                                <?php
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ?>
                                <td><?php echo $word[1]; ?></td>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt_word" placeholder="Tłumaczenie" required />
                                    <span id="check-e"></span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" name="btn-confirm" class="btn btn-default">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> &nbsp; END
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
            <?php
    }
```

At the begginning wordsArray() function explode class's variable and $words becomes an array: `[0]->wordLanguage1;wordLanguage2, [1]->wordLanguage1;wordLanguage2 etc..`.
$pol_ang is language option. If equals 1 then $_SESSION['correctAnswers'] becomes "wordsLanguage1", if equals 0 then becomes "wordLanguage2".
This function works fine. But what I wanna do is that my functio after ending the test should repeat asking for words that user entered incorrect. I can not find the solution to my problem

Comment: In your current code, is the form being sent to another page or the same page?

Comment: on the another page I declare it like:
$_SESSION['wordsId'] = $_GET['nr'];
$test->test($_GET['pol_ang']);

Comment: so from the above code, I don't get the big picture yet. I understand you are using a function to do a specific task, and I am assuming that in your other page you are using a `<form>` to input the data (correct me if I am wrong). If you are using a form in the previous page, why don't you just join the two pages into one page, have the form send to itself `<form action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method=...`, and by doing so, each time the user resends the form, the page will refresh, and the function will be called again as you wanted. Why not do that?

Comment: on the other page im doing nothing more than declaration I presented you on my last answer. This function prints form and does everything that my test should do. Everything happens in the function

Comment: so how are you obtaining input? where are you obtaining the input? is input being obtained on the page where your above code is placed? if it is, when you can do what I suggested and you should get the result you wanted.

Comment: oh sorry. $_SESSION['usersAnswerArray'] is the array where I collect all of the users answers. Then on the result page, where user is redirected at the end of the test, I compare it with $_SESSION['correctAnswers'] and I count the score. I dont know how to keep asking about incorrect answers